# there is no image in texture paint blender 2.82

Tags: image, texture-painting

[image]

In blender 2.82 what I expected was there should be an image in the viewport so that I can paint, chosing part of image as I wanted, but I can't do that because there's no image showing.

Is there any hotkey or UI to show image on viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to load a texture in the texture subpanel of the Bursh settings panel, and set its mapping to Stencil:

[image]

Comment: oh my god. i see. thank you so much. have a nice day!

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to up vote and set this as your topic's answer in the top left corner.